# Numerical Methods - Checking Domain of Phi(x)

Tags: numerical-methods

I have just started a MSc in Scientific Computing, and being an engineer my knowledge of real analysis is somewhat limited.

When rewriting f(x) = 0 as a fixed point formulation Phi(x) = x, it is stressed that we must check that for x in the interval [a,b] that Phi(x) maps into the same interval.

Is there a general real analysis method of checking this, using the Mean Value Theorem for example, or do I need to use simpler calculus method of checking the minimum and maximum values of Phi(x). The simpler calculus method doesn’t seem to be satisfactory or formal enough in a real analysis sense.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Kind regards

John

Comment: This is a pure mathematical problem. Please close this question and ask on http://math.stackexchange.com (using some $$ for mathjax). Even on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com this question is likely off-topic.

Comment: You must find the image of [a, b] by Phi. This is a simple variation study.